# Having problems using Forms input to upload file to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

So I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and trying to use a simple Form to upload a file to a web service.

I have the action attrib set to the url of my web service.  However, in firefox, I can't see that it is making any call to that service at all.
NOTE: I can throw int the below "Action" value to a browser minus the name of the web method and get a page showing the available web method so I believe the URL for the "Action" attribute is correct.

```
<form id="fileUpload" action="http://localhost/AcmeABC/services/FileUploadService.asmx/ImportRates" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="fileName"  name="fileName" />
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="fileArray"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.abc.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class FileUploadService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public void ImportRates(string fileName, byte[] fileArray) {
        try {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            string error = string.Format("Error thrown for file {0} with {1} error.", fileName, ex);
        }
    }
```

How can I see what is going on since I don't see any call be made.

I am also of the opinion that this might not be the best approach. I am new to the entire web development space so I am trying to find better ways of handling problems.  Please advice any other approach that might  be recommended for uploading a file to a web method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is in reading  the binary data as a parameter input. you needed to be read the data from HttpContext input stream**

Modify your webservice method as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public void ImportRates()
{
    try
    {


        //HTTP Context to get access to the submitted data
        HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;
        //File Collection that was submitted with posted data
        HttpFileCollection files = postedContext.Request.Files;
        //Make sure a file was posted
        string fileName =files[0].FileName;

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(files[0].InputStream);


    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        string error = string.Format("Error thrown for file {0} with {1} error.", fileName, ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geek.  I will try this. However, how does this get called the same way through the action attribute on the form?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Yes,No input parameter required in web service method.you have to made only one change in aspx add runat="server" tag in form section.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code in ImportRates web method? Does it look like the web method [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/uploadwithcsharpws05032007121259pm/uploadwithcsharpws.aspx)?

Another option to consider besides a web service for file upload is an [ASHX handler](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx). You can think of an ashx handler as an asp.net codebehind file without the view. Generally speaking ashx handlers are considered more lightweight than web services.

Comment: I will update my question with the current state of my web method.  It is similar to the link.  But i was just trying to read in the file and break point on it.  However, I never hit the break point nor does firebug show that any call was made to the service.

Comment: I would at least think it would report service not found.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that there is no port specified in the action url. This could be perfectly fine depending on your development environment but it's worth mentioning.